# Is it possible to run X event by clicking Y in jQuery(without accessing X)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guess there is two click event X and Y.

```
$('X').on('click',function(){
    //some function here
});
```

and

```
$('Y').on('click',function(){
    //this will run the X event
});
```

Here,At the same time I don't have access of trigger X . So I need to run that function/event by clicking Y trigger.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: You are looking for `http://api.jquery.com/trigger/`

Comment: Please search before posting. There are dozens of versions of this question on SO already.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('Y').on('click',function(){
   $('X').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$('Y').on('click',function(){
    $('X').trigger('click')
});
```

However, you can simply bind same event handler to both elements then you don't need to use the above method.

```
$('X, Y').on('click',function(){
    //Do something
});
```